# extract specific pattern separated by delimiter in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe with a column containing string

```r
nf1[1,"Info"] <- "AC=1;AF=0.500;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=-1.026e+00;ClippingRankSum=-1.026e+00;DP=4;ExcessHet=3.0103;FS=0.000;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.500;MQ=28.25;MQRankSum=-1.026e+00;QD=10.18;ReadPosRankSum=1.03;SOR=0.693
```

I would like to extract values for `AF`, `DP`, `QD`, `FS` into separate columns.

I tried

```r
library('splitstackshape')
cSplit(nf1[1,],"Info",";", "wide")
```

And I can then subset the required columns; but I am sure there are much better alternatives.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it happened likely because you showed no effort.

Comment: @Tim, i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sub` here:

```
sub(".*AF=(.*?)(?:;.*|$)", "\\1", x)
[1] "0.500"
```

You may easily modify the above to target other tags.

### Demo

Comment: i want to extract values for multiple factors. How would you use regular expression with multiple pattern?

Comment: What is wrong with multiple calls to `sub`?  Note that if you want _all_ tags then I would take a different approach using something like `strsplit`.